# Fourier Transform of Integral Expression

Tags: fourier-analysis, integral-transforms

I am trying to Fourier transform an expression containing an integral like this:
`FourierTransform[Integrate[f[v]*Cos[w[v]*t],{v,-v_0,v_0}],t,k]`
where
`f[v_] = Sqrt[3/(2 Pi)]*v/(Subscript[v, 0] Subscript[v,rms])*(Exp[-3*(v - Subscript[v, 0])^2/(2 Subscript[v, rms]^2)] -Exp[-3 (v + Subscript[v, 0])^2/(2 Subscript[v, rms]^2)])`
and `w[v]=w(1+v^2/2)`.
The problem is, that mathematica only returns the above expression (presumably because it does not want to exchange the order of integration?). Are there any
ways to tell mathematica to exchange the order of integration other than doing it by hand?

Comment: There are serious syntax problems with your expression.  Please start by writing valid Mathematica code. Probably you mean `FourierTransform[Integrate[f[v]*Cos[w[v]*t],{v,-vo,vo}],t,k]`? What are the definitions of `f[v]` and `w[v]`? Also `Blanck` (`_`) has a special meaning in Mathematica.

Comment: The expected answer is probably $\frac12 (f(w^{-1}(k))+f(w^{-1}(-k)))$, where $w^{-1}(w(x))=x$.

Comment: Yes, sorry I edited in the bracket after I realized I mistyped, and did not know how to type proper indices within the question.

Comment: `v_0` could mean something different MA than you expect.

Comment: Please, extend your post rather than adding explanations in the comments.

Comment: If I: `Integrate[
 FourierTransform[f[v]*Cos[w[v]*t], t, k] // FullSimplify // 
  Expand, {v, -Subscript[v, 0], Subscript[v, 0]}, 
 Assumptions -> {Subscript[v, 0] > 0, Subscript[v, rms] > 0, k > 0}]` give me answer.

Comment: Sure but now you changed the order of integration per hand,

Answer (score 1):

```
1/(2 \[Pi])
  Integrate[
  f[v]*Cos[w[v]*t] Exp[
    I*x*t], {t, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {v, -v0, v0}]

(* 1/(2 \[Pi]) \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(-v0\), \(v0\)]\(f[v]\ If[
    Im[w[v]] < Im[x] && Im[x + w[v]] < 0, 0, Integrate[
\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(I\ t\ x\)]\ Cos[
       t\ w[v]], {t, \(-\[Infinity]\), \[Infinity]}, 
     Assumptions -> \((Im[w[v]] >= Im[x] && 
         Im[x] <= 0)\) || \((Im[x] + Im[w[v]] >= 0 && 
         Im[x] > 0)\)]] \[DifferentialD]v\)\)  *)
```

??